# Yacc is prematurely stopping lexer?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I have a yacc file containing these rules:

```
%start program
.
.
.
statement
    : ';' { $$ = NULL; }
    | expression ';' { $$ = exprStmt($1); }
    | compound ';' { $$ = cmpndStmt($1); }
    ;

routine
    : routine statement { $$ = rtn($1, $2); }
    | { $$ = NULL; }
    ;

block
    : '{' routine '}' { $$ = $2; }
    ;

compound
    : block { $$ = cmpnd($1); }
    | if_cmpnd { $$ = $1; }
    ;

if_cmpnd
    : IF expression compound { $$ = ifcmpnd($2, $3); }
    | if_cmpnd ELSE compound { $$ = elsecmpnd($1, $3); }
    ;

program
    : routine { printf("YACC finish\n"); exit(0); }
    ;
```

For this parser, I gave a sample text file containing:

```
var a := 6
var b := 5
if a<5 {
b = 2
}
else {
b = 20
}
```

But during parsing, with debug, I got this output

```
.
.
.
--accepting rule at line 47 ("if")
--accepting rule at line 62 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 47 ("a")
--accepting rule at line 56 ("<")
--accepting rule at line 29 ("5")
--accepting rule at line 62 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 57 ("{")
--accepting rule at line 60 ("
")
--accepting rule at line 47 ("b")
--accepting rule at line 56 (" = ")
--accepting rule at line 29 ("2")
--accepting rule at line 60 ("
")
--accepting rule at line 57 ("}")
--accepting rule at line 60 ("
")
--accepting rule at line 47 ("else")
YACC finish
```

As it can be seen, the block after else is not lexed. But instead, if I replace "else" by something else like "if a>8" text is lexed till the EOF. I'm not getting the cause of it. Someone help me out please.

Comment: Someone plz tell me, until when parser keeps calling yylex() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You complain that YACC is prematurely terminating. That's easily explained; your parser includes: (empasis added)

```
program
    : routine { printf("YACC finish\n"); exit(0); }
```

and the entire purpose of `exit(0)` is to terminate prematurely. So it's doing the job you asked it to do. However, it's hard to imagine a use case in which calling `exit()` from a parser action is correct, and the results you're getting show why.

It's particularly important to note that bison/yacc parsers (and especially bison parsers) may perform reductions before signalling an error, even in cases where the error token does not appear in the follow list for the production being reduced. That's probably the case here; had you not called `exit()`, you would have gotten a syntax error indication, which at least would have been less mysterious (and which could have been handled with an `error`-handling production in your grammar).

`yyparse` will return (with a return value of 0) if it manages to parse the entire input; it will return 1 if it encounters a syntax error and 2 if it detects memory over-use. (There are preprocessor symbols for these constants, but it is usually sufficient to test whether the return value of `yyparse()` was zero or not.) You should always allow the parser to return normally, to give it an opportunity to clean up allocated resources before returning.

You don't show your scanner, and the only trace you present is a trace of the scanner, not the parser. So it's not possible to know what token type the parser received when the scanner encountered the `else` token. Enabling [parser traces](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracing) instead of (or as well as) scanner traces would provide information more useful in debugging the parser (including the token type of each token passed to the parser).

However, I was struck by the fact that `if` and `else` are both handled by the same scanner action as your identifiers (at line 47 of your scanner description). That implies that your scanner does not have specific rules for each keyword. Presumably, you are doing something inefficient and error-prone like compare identifier tokens with each possible keyword in order to return the correct token type to the parser. But it's hard to do more than guess about this because of lack of information.

Comment: Yes, at line 47 I'm matching identifier token, and then comparing it with each possible keyword. But this was the preferred way to match keywords as given in [this](https://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/~bivasm/notes/LexAndYaccTutorial.pdf) pdf page 35.

Comment: Parser 'exits' when it matches a complete routine, which left recursion of statements. Hence doesn't it mean that, until an EOF is read, routine must recursively go on adding statements?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, if the second block was an `if` instead of `else`, parser would parse till the end. So I suspect my grammar was wrong and not the scanner. So I not included the scanner code. Do you want it?

Comment: @Sourav: I disagree strongly with that tutorial (at least with respect to keyword parsing). It does produce lexers with fewer states, but the resulting savings are trivial (except possibly on extremely memory-limited embedded devices) and you still have to store the token lookup table and the code to use it, which is a cost both in executable size and execution time.

Comment: @Sourav: Assuming that the lexer did not send the correct token for `exit`, then the parser *has* seen a complete `routine`. It has not seen an input consisting only of a complete `routine`, so there is a syntax error because it was expecting an EOF token, but it has clearly seen a complete `routine`. So it does the reduction and the reduction  calls `exit()`. If that comes from an example in the same tutorial, I'd throw the tutorial in the trash and find a better one. Reading the bison manual itself is almost always a better idea than random tutorials in the internet.

Comment: @Sourav: It's pointless to insert a trace for a scanner which you don't include. Rather than include the scanner, I'd suggest including the trace produced by bison. (But, as I said, it's likely that if you look at the bison trace, you will immediately see the problem.) In any case, before just pasting your scanner into your question, I suggest you test it by just printing out the token type and (if appropriate) semantic value for a representative sequence of tokens (including, for example, the various keywords you expect it to recognise).

Comment: Bison trace? did you mean .output file? if not tell how to get it. Btw, this was not from that tutorial.

Comment: @Sourav: On the contrary, your tutorial shows exactly the same error on page 24, and it is likely to have the same consequence: erroneous input will be silently discarded instead of producing a syntax error message.

Comment: Thanks for the help... I found out why parser was reducing to routine. But can I stop it from going to `program` state when the lookahead token is not $end. Instead of silently reducing into final state and exiting, I want it to raise a syntax error.

Comment: @sourav: Just don't call `exit()`. The parser will call `yyerror` (which is supposed to print the error messge it receives). Then the parser will return 1, so you might want to check the return value in the call to `yyparse()`.

Comment: The `routine` action will still be executed; that's the way bison works. In general terms, you should avoid doing anything in any action which would be a problem if the parse eventually terminates with a syntax error.

Comment: Giving credit where credit is due, that tutorial does explain how to enable [parsing traces](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracing) at the top o page 40. But reading the section in the bison manual is recommended.